# Calculating the Jacobian for a linear transformation (in Kadane's 'Principles of Uncertainty')

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $Y=BXB^T$, where $B$ is non-singular, and $X$ is a symmetric non-sigular $n\times n$ matrix.

According to the book [Principles of Uncertainty](http://uncertainty.stat.cmu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/principles-of-uncertainty.pdf), on page 316, if $B$ is a matrix of type ($i$), just as defined in page 315, $B=\text{Diag}(1,...,1,a,1,...,1)$, then the Jacobian related to the transformation on $X$ is $a^{n+1}$. How is this true?

For example, according to the book, the following is the Jacobian of our transformation Y for $n=4$:

$\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & a & 1 & 1 \\
 a & a^2 & a & a \\
 1 & a & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & a & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right|$. However, if I ask mathematica to calculate this, I get $0$, which is clearly at odds with what's stated on the book. So, where did I go wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the dimension $n=2$. Transformation: $Y=BXB^T$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1&y_3\\y_2&y_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_3\\x_2&x_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

After some calculations, one obtains:

$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\\y_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a^2&ac&ac&c^2\\ab&ad&bc&cd\\ab&bc&ad&dc\\b^2&bd&bd&d^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$$

It is of importance to know that the $n^2 \times n^2=4 \times 4$ matrix $K$ of the above system can in fact be obtained through the Kronecker (or tensor) product $K=B \otimes B$, by the important identity that you will find in the Wikipedia article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

$$Y=BXB^T \ \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \ \ vec(Y)=(B \otimes B)vec(X)$$

Either by calculating it directly or by applying results on the Kronecker product, one obtains in this way the jacobian:

$$det(K)=det(B)^4$$

**Edit**: Let us call $\alpha$ what you have denoted $a$ (in order to avoid confusions).

Equations of p. 316, taking $i=2$ ($\alpha$ is in 2nd position in $B=diag(1,\alpha)$) become

$$\begin{cases}y_{22} &=& \alpha^2x_{22}\\
y_{21} &=& \alpha x_{21} \\
y_{11} &=& x_{11} 
\end{cases}  \ (*) \ \ \text{with my notations:} \ \ \begin{cases}y_{4} &=& \alpha^2x_{4}\\
y_{2} &=& \alpha x_{2} \\
y_{1} &=& x_{1} 
\end{cases} $$

and the result, in conformity with the general structure of $K$ given above, with $a=1,b=0,c=0,d=\alpha$ is:

$$K=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&\alpha&0&0\\0&0&\alpha&0\\0&0&0&\alpha^2\end{bmatrix}  \ \ \text{instead of} \ \ \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \alpha & 1 & 1 \\
\alpha & \alpha^2 & \alpha & \alpha \\
 1 & \alpha & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & \alpha & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

with $det(K)=$$\alpha^4$.

(the issue was the interpretation of $i$ in equations (*), I think)

Remark: In my opinion, this book, whose general content I don't discuss (I know few things in this area) is not very advisable regarding matrix computations: it has a heavy computational approach, ignorant to now common knowledge. For example, in page 315, it rediscovers Cholesky factorization, without naming it, without mentioning the condition of definite positivity!.. Kronecker product, now in all linear algebra books, is absent, etc.

Comment: JeanMarie, many thanks for your answer. I agree with it. However, I would also like to know/learn  how or what I did wrong as stated in my question.

Comment: I add an "Edit" to my answer in order to explain it.

Comment: Jean, I'm having a bit of trouble to understand how your deductions relate to the Jacobian of the Transformation... What's the Jacobian in your case? Is it K?

Comment: As the change of variables $(x_1\cdots x_4) \rightarrow (y_1\cdots y_4)$  is linear, and expressed by by matrix $K$, it is its own jacobian __matrix__ (no need to take partial derivatives ); thus its jacobian __determinant__ is $det(K)$.

Comment: Many thanks! I got it.

Comment: JeanMarie, may I interest you in this other question? Thanks.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744995/calculating-the-jacobian-for-a-linear-transformation-kadanes-principles-of-un